# Obtener repositorios de un usuario de GitHub con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, github

Que tal? Queria hacer una consulta porque estoy queriendo mostrar los repositorios de un usuario de GitHub y no se que es lo que no esta bien... En la consola tampoco me esta tirando ningun error.

**El codigo de Javascript es este:**

```
function getRepositorie() {
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var search = document.getElementById("git").value;
request.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=" + search, true);
request.onload = () => show_list(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
console.log("consola" + request.responseText);
request.send();}

function show_list(user) {
var userList = document.getElementsByClassName("user-list")[0];
var userUl = document.createElement("ul");
var valor = user;

for (var i = 0; i < user.items.lenght; i++) {
    var userLi = document.createElement("li");
    var userRepo = document.createTextNode("_" + usert.items[i].name);
    userLi.appendChild(userRepo);
    userUl.appendChild(userLi);
}
userList.appendChild(userUl);}
```

**Y el codigo de HTML es este:**

```
<body>
<header>Get Repositorie</header>


<div class="user-info">
    <h3> Search the repositories of a GitHub user</h3>
    Enter the User: <input type="text" id="git" placeholder="What user are you looking for?">
    <button onclick="getRepositorie()">Search!</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
</div>

<div class="user-list">

</div>
```

¿Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Editado:
Ahora por consola me esta tirando este error...
[image: Error]

Saludos!

Answer (score 3):

El problema principal creo yo es la URL de la API. Realmente, [según indica Github](https://api.github.com) (ver la clave llamada `user_repositories_url` en el JSON) el formato para acceder a los repositorios de un determinado usuario es el siguiente:

```
https://api.github.com/users/{user}/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}
```

Por lo que si construyes tu URL de este modo debería funcionarte:

```
"https://api.github.com/users/" + search + "/repos"
```

Veamos una prueba. He puesto por defecto mi usuario en el `input`. Lo quitas en tu escenario real. También puedes probar con otro usuario.

```js
function getRepositorie() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var search = document.getElementById("git").value;
  request.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/users/" + search + "/repos", true);
  request.onload = () => show_list(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
  console.log("consola" + request.responseText);
  request.send();
}

function show_list(user) {
  var userList = document.getElementsByClassName("user-list")[0];
  var userUl = document.createElement("ul");
  var valor = user;
  
  for (var i in user) {
    var userLi = document.createElement("li");
    var userRepo = document.createTextNode("_" + user[i].name);
    userLi.appendChild(userRepo);
    userUl.appendChild(userLi);
  }
  userList.appendChild(userUl);
}
```

```html
<div class="user-info">
  <h3> Search the repositories of a GitHub user</h3>
  Enter the User: <input type="text" id="git" placeholder="What user are you looking for?" value="padrecedano">
  <button onclick="getRepositorie()">Search!</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
</div>

<div class="user-list">

</div>
```

---

La URL con este formato

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q={query}
```

es más bien para buscar en los repositorios (cualesquiera) según determinados criterios. Por ejemplo, si quieres buscar los repositorios para `android`, por el nombre del mismo, por su contenido, etc.

El sentido de esa URL es explicado con detalle en el apartado [**Searching for repositories**](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-for-repositories/).

Aquí tienes un ejemplo que trae los repositorios de Android.

```js
function getRepositorie() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var search = document.getElementById("git").value;
  request.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=" + search, true);
  request.onload = () => show_list(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
  console.log("consola" + request.responseText);
  request.send();
}

function show_list(user) {
  var userList = document.getElementsByClassName("user-list")[0];
  var userUl = document.createElement("ul");
  var valor = user;
  console.log(`Hay un total de ${user.total_count} repositorios`);
}
```

```html
<div class="user-info">
  <h3> Search the repositories of a GitHub user</h3>
  Enter the User: <input type="text" id="git" placeholder="What user are you looking for?" value="android">
  <button onclick="getRepositorie()">Search!</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
</div>

<div class="user-list">

</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder! Al final no era un problema de la URL, era algo mucho mas sencillo y error mio... En el for que hago en la funccion "show_list" tengo un error de sintaxis... escribi "lenght" en vez de "length".

Muchas gracias por responder!

Comment: @GFonzii aunque te funcione así, ten en cuenta lo que explica la API sobre la forma de buscar. Si quieres los repositorios de un usuario en específico lo lógico es que busques así: `https://api.github.com/users/{user}/repos`  y puedes incluso poner más filtros si quieres. Haciéndolo de otro modo estarías leyendo filtrando entre miles/millones de repositorios innecesariamente. Ese `for`  que mencionas, se puede escribir también de una forma más nítida y elegante, si te fijas en el código de mi respuesta.